# Signalr for DotNetCore 2 packages missing all JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget-package, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to get Signalr from Nuget and have installed every package I can find, but can't seem to find the client JavaScript files that should be included. I've run the command from the package manager (in Visual Studio 2017)

```
npm install @aspnet/signalr
```

But alas, there is no /lib/signalr/signalr.js file anywhere. The Client stuff should be there. Where can I download this?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! What the docs do not tell you is that the scripts are dumped into the following folder in the solution folder

```
node_modules\@aspnet\signalr\dist\browser
```

and there it was signalr.js (and the minimized version as well)
You create a folder called signalr under wwwroot/lib and place it there.